# python V3 def __defaults__ tuple doesn't include default values associated with keyword-only parameters?

Tags: python, function, parameters

This question is regarding parameters for V3 Python functions. I wonder why keyword-only parameters that have default values associated with them  don't seem to get their default values added to the __defaults__ tuple?

Here is an example:

```
def test_def( ap, bp, cn=2.3, *, dn, fn = 'default keyword-only', **gn ):
    """
    Test function definition

    :param ap: Mandatory positional parameter
    :param bp: Mandatory positional paramter
    :param cn: Optional named parameter (a.k.a keyword parameter)
    :param dn: Mandatory keyword-only parameter
    :param fn: Optoinal keyword-only paramter
    :param gn: **kwds
    :return:
    """
    print( 'ap: ', ap )
    print( 'bp: ', bp )
    print( 'cn: ', cn )
    print( 'dn: ', dn )
    print( 'fn: ', fn )
    for elem in gn:
        print("gn: ", gn)

test_def( 89, 'text instead', abc=12, dn='my keyword-only value' )
```

Here is the output:

>>> test_def( 89, 'text instead', abc=12, dn='my keyword-only value' )
pa:  89
bp:  text instead
cn:  2.3
dn:  my keyword-only value
fn:  default keyword-only
gn:  {'abc': 12}
>>> print(test_def.__defaults__)
(2.3,)

The __defaults__ tuple does include the default value for cn but not fn. How comes?

Comment: Defaults for keyword-only arguments are stored in `__kwdefaults__`.

Comment: Beautiful... thank you!

Comment: Should'nt @vaultah "answer" be an answer so it can be marked as answered?

Comment: I was thinking that too... maybe we can persuade Vaultah to change his comment to an answer?